Ubuntu 22.04 is stuck at boot screen mismatch between UUIDs
I am having trouble booting my newly updated Ubuntu 22.04, i installed Ubuntu 20.04 a whilr ago on a dual boot configuration with windows 10, the installation did not went very smoothly as there were many errors and incompatibility that i was not expecting but at the end of the day i managed to make it work.
Yesterday Ubuntu updated from 20.04 to 22.04 and when it restarted it wouldn't boot.
I am not an expert on linux but i managed to more or less find out that there was something wrong with the /boot/efi partition, by typing:
mount /boot/efi


Which resulted:
mount: /boot/efi: can't find UUID=ED6A-5652

I figured there must be a mismatch between the UUIDs in /etc/fstab.
I tried some diagnostics such as:
sudo vi /etc/fstab

sudo blkid

Which resulted in:
/boot/efi was on /dev/sda5 during installation

UUID=ED6A-5652  /boot/efi       vfat      umask=0077

/dev/sda5: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="B69A77699A7724D1" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="208e952d-06"


*Apologize in advance for mistakes in grammar and or spelling.
Update:
Earlier i posted a question about my Ubuntu 22.04 being stuck at emergency mode, following up:
I am Dual-booting Ubuntu with Windows 10, I installed 20.04 but then Ubuntu updated it and it since then i was not able to boot.
Running mount /boot/efi returns mount: /boot/efi: can't find UUID=ED6A-5652
Some other diagnostics:
cat /etc/fstab:
#/etc/fstab: static file system information.

# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>     <dump>   <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=a89f5691-7c5c-484f-9f54-182226d1bf89 /            ext4     errors=remount-ro 0     1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=ED6A-5652 /boot/efi         vfat    umask=0077  0         1
/swapfile                                 none         swap      sw            0       0

lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid:
NAME      FSTYPE   SIZE FSUSED  LABEL PARTLABEL MOUNTPOINT UUID                                 PARTUUID
sda              931,5G
└─sda1    ntfs   299,4G                                    F612E2D212E29741                     208e952d-01
└─sda2    ntfs     568M                                    F67E84727E842D85                     208e952d-02
└─sda3               1K                                                                         208e952d-03
└─sda5    ntfs     244M                                    B69A77699A7724D1                     208e952d-05
└─sda6    ext4   345,3G 224,3G                  /          a89f5691-7c5c-484f-9f54-182226d1bf89 208e952d-06

sudo efibootmgr -v:
EFI variables are not supported on this system.
It seems that the boot partition is in the wrong filesystem (ntfs) and it is also mismatching the UUIDs, how do i solve this?

The ESP has to be FAT32 not NTFS. Post cat /etc/fstab and full lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid and sudo efibootmgr -v  UEFI should use partUUID to find ESP. And ESP should be in fstab by UUID.

Edited the question with the diagnostics.
